# is there an error in my VBA for Excel sheets to a multiple PDF files

Tags: excel, vba

Very easy VBA, but continuously giving me an error on Excel for Mac. Any leads? Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportSheetsToPDFs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mywsname As String
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    mywsname = ws.Name
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    FileName:="C:\" & mywsname & ".pdf", _
    openafterpublish:=True
    
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This has been covered so many times before in stackoverflow. Type `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat MAC site:stackoverflow.com` in google

Comment: `FileName:="C:\" & mywsname & ".pdf"` BTW this is the path in a windows PC. For Mac the path would be something like `FileName:= "HDD:Users:USER:Desktop:" & mywsname & ".pdf"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save as pdf using Mac Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473104/save-as-pdf-using-mac-excel-vba)

Comment: @SiddharthRout What should I add to this script so the script capture not only Workbook name, but add right after the name of the sheet would add the file name as well? Thank you!