Windows vs Mac file export a PDF
Below is the code I wrote to produce a PDF file. It prints a specific sheet and not the active sheet.
Sub Save_PDF_Pay_Slip()
    
    Sheet14.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, _
                "E:\TrackSlips\" & Sheet1.Range("H3").Value & _
                           " - " & Sheet1.Range("H6").Value & _
                           " - " & Sheet1.Range("C3").Value & ".pdf"
    
    Response = MsgBox("Tracking Slip PDF File Created", vbOKOnly, "PDF File Message")
    
End Sub

Simple and basically one line of code. The user clicks on a button I created call Print Tracking Slip.
What would be the code on a Mac laptop? Suggestions appreciated.
I appears to send the file to a printer.

Please [edit] your question to format it properly. Read Markdown help for reference.

If you want to customize the file path based on the OS, you could use Application.OperatingSystem property (Excel) | Microsoft Learn

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473104/save-as-pdf-using-mac-excel-vba
